# LinqToMongo Inject

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a .NET app which uses MongoDB so I am using the Mongo C# driver.

The driver version I am currently using is 1.9.2 and everything in my app works as expected.  However I am trying to upgrade the Mongo driver to latest version 2.7.0 however I am having some issues getting some things working.

The below Code snippet is where I am facing an issue with latest version of driver

```
    public IQueryable<Location> SearchByLocationDistance(double latitude, double longitude, double rangeInKm)

    {        

        var rangeInMeters = rangeInKm * 1000;        

        var point = GeoJson.Point(GeoJson.Geographic(longitude, latitude));

        var locationClause = Query<Location>.Near(y => y.Address.GeoPoint, point, rangeInMeters);

        var query = collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => locationClause.Inject());



        return query;

    }
```

The error message I get is:

*The LinqToMongo.Inject method is only intended to be used in LINQ Where clauses.*

Doing some research it looks like a fix was checked in for this - https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1445

However I am not sure if I need to use new syntax in order to achieve the same functionality.

I tried changing my code as below:

```
var filter = Builders<Location>.Filter.Near(y => y.Address.GeoPoint, point, rangeInMeters);

var query = collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.filter.Inject());
```

but with that code I get a different error message - *$near is not allowed inside of a $match aggregation*

Answer (score -1):

Got this working with the below code:

```
    public IQueryable<Location> SearchByLocationDistance(double latitude, double longitude, double rangeInKm)
    {         
        var rangeInMeters = rangeInKm * 1000;         
        var point = GeoJson.Point(GeoJson.Geographic(longitude, latitude)); //long, lat
        var filter = Builders<Location>.Filter.Near(y => y.Address.GeoPoint, point, rangeInMeters);

        return collection.Find(filter).ToList().AsQueryable();
    }
```