# c# mongodb filter definition inject

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a scenario where I can either query data from a cache or mongo db. I initially wrote the predicate as `FilterDefinition<T>`, now I want to use it to filter the cached data using linq.

I tried the following `cachedData.AsQueryable().Where(e => filterDef.Inject())`, but I get an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LinqExtensions.Inject method is only intended to be used in LINQ Where clauses.

What does this error mean? Am I misunderstanding what this api does?

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352209/linqtomongo-inject

Comment: Yes, but the solution does not work for me.